# How yo use Type.GetType() to pass an unknown type at runtime to a Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

There is a slight possibility I could have worded the title incorrectly and  I apologize if this comes across as already answered (and I just have not found it).

Having said that I have searched this site for several hours and have come across several very involved attempts (not clear enough) of using reflection, which I don't want to use because of performance reasons. I am already using Type.GetType() which searches through the .dll to find the type.

So, without further ado, here goes..

I have a method in a class that accepts a generic type:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public TList Execute<TList, TItem>(string text)
        where TList : ICollection<TItem>, new()
        where TItem : new()
    {
        TList list = new TList();
        TItem item = new TItem();
        ...set properties and add to list...
        ...implementation not important...
        return list;
    }
}
```

Usage (calling method):

```
public void callingMethod(string typeNameString, string typeItemNameString)
{
    Type T = Type.GetType(typeNameString);
    Type Ti = Type.GetType(typeItemNameString);

    SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();

    // and here is where things falls apart drastically..
    // not sure exactly what to do here as it seems noting works
    var result = sc.Execute<T,Ti>("hello text"); //no luck..'T' is a variable but used as a type
    var result = sc.Execute<Type.GetType(typeNameString),Ti>("hello text"); //no luck...operator '<' cannot be appliedto operands of type 'method group' and 'Type'

    //This works fine
    List<Invoice> _invoices = sc.Execute<Invoices, Invoice>("hello text");
}

public class Invoice
{ //properties omitted }

public class Invoices : List<Invoice>
{}
```

This seems like a very straight forward/logical approach, but is proving not to be the case.

What am I missing?

I appreciate the time and dedication individuals take to respond to questions on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the <> notation because the compiler actually creates the class with the type built in. Hence it must be known at compile time. For what you are trying to do you must use reflection.